# Is there an equivalent of plyr's .inform in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

`plyr` has a very convenient option, `.inform = TRUE`, which lets user know which pieces in the split-apply-combine process fails.

Is there an equivalent way to know which piece fails with `dplyr`'s `group_by`?

A minimal example: group 1 in the following `df` is the group causing problem, but `dplyr` error message doesn't reveal that information.

```
df <- data.frame(group = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2))
df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(value = c(10, 10, 10))
# Error: incompatible size (3), expecting 2 (the group size) or 1
```

Comment: Looking at the help file of `?group_by`, there's no indication that such an option exists (whereas it's documented in `?plyr::ddply`) and I haven't seen it being using anywhere until now. However, I assume that the error you'd get would let you know whether it's in a `mutate`, `summarise`, `filter`... or other dplyr function following a `group_by` operation. Perhaps you can give an example where this is not clear?

Comment: I added a minimal example.

Comment: In your example, the size of the first group is 2 (1, 1) but you try to create a new column in the mutate call with 3 values (=rows) which is impossible in the dplyr-world. Is this example a case which is unclear to you?

Comment: I construct the example so that it fails. The point of the example is to show that `dplyr` does not tell us which group fails. In contrast, if I attempt something similar with `plyr` and `.inform = TRUE`, `plyr` will tell me that it is group 1 that causes the failure. In real applications, it won't be so clear at a glance which group fails, hence `.inform = TRUE` is very valuable.

Comment: I see what you mean. As I said, I'm not aware of such functionality currently implemented in dplyr (CRAN version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a way within `dplyr`, so this may be a bit orthogonal to what you're looking for, but here's a potential approach using `split` and `purrr::possibly`.

```
library(purrr); library(dplyr)

set_3_tens <- function(df) { df %>% mutate(value = c(10,10,10)) }

df %>%
  split(.$group) %>%
  map(
    possibly(
      set_3_tens, otherwise = "Problem in group"))

$`1`
[1] "Problem in group"

$`2`
  group value
1     2    10
2     2    10
3     2    10
```

Comment: This solution does solve my root problem, which is how to debug in a functional programming framework. Another solution I came up with is to include a tryCatch block inside the function that's being mapped. That way, when an error is encountered, I can choose how to handle it (e.g. print out the error message, print out the data in that piece).